# BIOS options not unlocked

Tags: bios, virtualization

New poster, long-time PC user. Frustrated at my motherboard for trying to enable virtualization, not getting anywhere fast.

Problem in short: Accessing the BIOS, most options are greyed out, unable to interact with anything important. Trying to disable "secure boot". Have MSI B550 wifi motherboard, Ryzen 9 5950X, & 3080TI now that pricing dropped.

How do I enable all options?

Thanks

Comment: Are you at least on [BIOS AMI BIOS7C91vAA](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/MAG-B550-TOMAHAWK/support) from 2022-06-06?

Comment: Gaming Edge Wifi, but I'll download the latest drivers and see if that helps

Comment: You may try the suggestion from the answer below but if you do then NEVER loose/forget the password. There's no way to reset it, only replacing the motherboard itself will do.

Answer (score 1):

This has happened to me, if disabling secure boot is greyed out, set a supervisor password. It maybe called something else for you but it is most likely under the security tab. This will enable you to disable secure boot

Comment: Had the same problem, setting a supervisor pw fixed it for me, too

Comment: dont forget the password!